# HERE Isoline API V8 doesn't account for traffic

Tags: isochrone, here-maps

I am playing with HERE Isoline API v8.4.0 and it works pretty well. The [documentation](http://%5Bdocumentation%5D(https://developer.here.com/documentation/isoline-routing-api/8.4.0/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/departure-time-isoline.html)) mentions that setting `departureTime` parameter will include traffic in isochrone calculation. However, the results returned for me have the exact same geometries for any given times (tested in Berlin, Warsaw times 5AM and 5PM). The requests are properly structured. Anyone else knows this problem?

Example parameter values:

```
'departureTime': '2021-01-03T17:00:00'
'departureTime': '2021-01-03T04:15:00'
```

Comment: I remember this worked in V7 using something similar to `mode=shortest;car;traffic:enabled`

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But the newer version does not have `traffic` option. According to docs it starts working if you specify the departure or arrival time.

Comment: So V7 yields different results using the same options in V7 format?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it. It might be a different engine underneath. Using V7 I managed to get different results depending on input time. Still, V7 is marked on their website as `in maintenance` and I'm not sure if I should get used to it.